# cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++, shellexecute

```
int main() {

    string url;
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    cout << "Enter url: ";
    cin >> url;
    cout << "how many times do you want to open the url?: ";
    cin >> a;
    while (b<a)
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", url.c_str, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL); 
        b++
        }
        cin >> a;
        }
```

//the part that is giving me trouble 
is the "open part says it cannot convert //itShellExecuteW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,INT)': cannot convert //argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: Use `ShellExecuteA`.  `ShellExecute` is a macro that expands to `ShellExecuteA` or `ShellExecuteW` if you are building for Unicode.  You must be building with Unicode set.  See (at the bottom): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Use wstring, wcout, wcin.  Or use ShellExecuteA().  https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

Call ShellExecuteA instead of ShellExecute, the windows API has a huge number of macros that decide between ANSI and Unicode versions

Comment: okay thank you but what do i do to fix this? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C3867 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str